# 'import IN' in python

Tags: python, sockets

I found a python programm, this program use:

```
import IN
```

But when I try to run it, it says to me: No module named 'IN'
Im looking for a librarie named of this way but nothing appears.  Im using python 3.5 for windows.  I would appreciate answers.

The code is next:

```
import IN
import socket, sys
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

MAX=65535
PORT=9999

if len(sys.argv)!=2:
    print (sys.stderr, 'usage: sender.py host')
    sys.exit(2)

hostname=sys.argv[1]
s.connect((hostname,PORT))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, IN.IP_MTU_DISCVER, IN.IP_PMTUDISC_D0)
try:
    s.send('#'*65000)
except socket.error:
    print ('The message did not make it')
    option=getattr(IN, 'IP_MTU',14)
    print('MTU:', s.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, option))
else:
    print ('MTU:', s.getsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, option))
```

Comment: It might be a user-defined library or another script in the same directory being imported

Comment: Perhaps is a modules written by whoever wrote the program you are referring to. There's no guarantee it is public.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like values from linux header file interface `include/uapi/linux/in.h`

```
IP_PMTUDISC_D0 = 2
IP_MTU_DISCVER = 10
IP_MTU = 14
```

I don't know if your `IN.py` is public, or private (as other suggest), but if you're only missing a few values (as listed in your sample code) you can easily re-create it.